# Snapshot live feed featurelayer by creating a copy of the data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, feature-layer, duplication

Let's say we have a feature layer on ArcGIS online that is constantly updated.  Examples would be the [Recent Conditions in Air Quality (PM2.5)](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8dcf5d4e124f480fa8c529fbe25ba04e), [Satellite (VIIRS) Thermal Hotspots and Fire Activity](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=dece90af1a0242dcbf0ca36d30276aa3), or in my particular case, the [Recent Hurricanes, Cyclones and Typhoons](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=adfe292a67f8471a9d8230ef93294414) layer.

These layers are constantly changing, but I want to create a snapshot of the data as is, so that I can have a record of say, Hurricane data from 2020, or Air Quality forecast from today.  I tried following the [Copy and save layers](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/copy-save-layers.htm) tutorial for ArcGIS online, and I ended up with [Hurricanes, Cyclones and Typhoons - Observed Position - 2020](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5031e3b805b44296938f33a3e619a186), but I quickly realized that this is just referencing the original data, it does not create a snapshot as a new data source.

I tried opening a projectin ArcGIS Pro and bringing in the layers, hoping that I could export the features to a new dataset and then publish that data as a new layer.  But when trying to go to export the data, the option is greyed out:

[image]

What can I do to export / copy this data and publish it as a new layer that does *not* update alongside its original source?

Surely there must be a way.  I have access to ArcGIS Online and Pro, and my eventual goal is to publish the layers on ArcGIS online and then consume them in an ArcGIS API for JavaScript app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI seems to have deactivated the download options for this layer. However I was was able to download the feature layer by using the 'Feature Class to Feature Class' tool in ArcGIS Pro. First load the Hurricane FeatureServer into ArcGIS Pro, select the tool and choose your desired sublayer as the input.
If you want to automate the whole process you can acces the data via the REST API and query the data there (see https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/Recent_Hurricanes_v1/FeatureServer/0//query).

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  There is so much to learn about ArcGIS pro.